# Как в список передавать объект, а не ссылку на него

Tags: python

Имеется такой код

```
class Data():
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
list_obj = []
obj = Data(111)
list_obj.append(obj)

obj.num = 2
list_obj.append(obj)

obj.num = 3
list_obj.append(obj)
# на выходе у всех трех объектов num равняется 3
```

Из-за того, что в списке находится ссылка на объект, а не объект, то значение `obj.num` изменится у всех элементов в итоге на 3. Как в списке хранить не ссылку на объект, а сам объект?

Comment: В Python объекты всегда передаются по ссылке. Чтобы не менялось везде, передавайте копию объекта.

Comment: А как копию объекта сделать?

Comment: В простейшем случае можно использовать функцию copy из модуля copy. Чтобы прописать конкретный код, который должен выполняться при копировании вашего объекта, нужно у него прописать метод `__copy__` (который будет создавать определенным образом копию вашего объекта).

Comment: В принципе, то, что нужно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите, чтобы это были **разные объекты** с **разными значениями**, то и создавайте каждый раз **новый объект**, а не меняйте значение у **одного и того же** объекта:

```
obj2 = Data(2)
list_obj.append(obj2)

obj3 = Data(3)
list_obj.append(obj3)
```

А у вас получается, что вы хотите менять свойство **одного и того же объекта**, но так, чтобы этот объект хранил разные значения, будучи помещённым в список в разные моменты времени. Это что-то противоречивое. Либо объект один и он хранит одинаковые значения, сколько ссылок на него не ставь, либо это всё-таки разные объекты и тогда они могут хранить разные значения.

Можно, конечно, и копию объекта делать, после чего менять у него свойство, но зачем? Если бы это был объект с множеством полей, значения которых вы хотели бы сохранить, тогда ещё понятно. Но и в этом случае лучше делать новый объект в явном виде, чтобы не запутаться, где объект, где копия, где что.

В случае, если нужна именно копия, всё-таки лучше сделать в классе отдельный метод для создания копии объекта и в этом методе делать копию объекта в явном виде, и менять поле, которое нужно поменять. Какие-то вещи можно скопировать через `copy.deepcopy`, но лучше, когда вы сами управляете копированием состояния объекта, оно может быть не такое уж и простое, с какой-то дополнительной логикой.

Comment: неееее, так не вариант делать, у объекта может быть 100 параметров, а разница в значении только у одного и придется вводить постоянно одни и теже значения, что бы в итоге ввести одно другое

Comment: @helldrg А, понятно. Дополню ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: Если кратко, этот код полностью сделает копию объекта? `obj2 = copy.deepcopy(obj)`

Comment: @helldrg, то, что вы пытаетесь сделать - опасная практика. Вы изменяете данные объекта, но пытаетесь сохранить старое (на момент в прошлом) состояние __того же__ объекта. Объясните хотя бы для чего все это нужно.

Comment: Постараюсь объяснить, есть массив объектов, я сравниваю данные этих объектов, создаю новый объект, содержащий ссылку на нужный объект и записываю дополнительные данные. Таких новых объектов создается много и все они добавляются в список и тут была проблема, что я передавал в список ссылку на новый объект, так как он у меня назывался tmp_obj и когда менял дополнительные данные во всех элементах списка они менялись. copy.deepcopy(tmp_obj) исправил это дело. А вообще начальный массив объектов - это объекты содержащие координаты и информацию об объекте. Ищу оптимальный маршрут

Comment: Новые объекты это ссылка на объект с координатами и параметры дистанция, время итд. Новые объекты добавляю в список. Список это конкретный маршрут

Answer (score 0):

У Вас выходит, что объект - это изменяемая переменная,чтобы передавать в список как значение, нужно сделать копию изменяемого элемента.

Можете использовать библиотеку copy для Вашего объекта.

```
import copy

class Data():
  def __init__(self, num):
    self.num = num

list_obj = []
obj = Data(111)
list_obj.append(copy.copy(obj))

obj.num = 2
list_obj.append(copy.copy(obj))

obj.num = 3
list_obj.append(copy.copy(obj))
```

Comment: `copy.copy` не подходит, параметр может быть списком

Comment: Ну тогда, действительно, как писали выше перегрузить для своего класса метод `__copy__()`

Comment: я так понимаю `__copy__()` он нужен, что бы скопировать объект с определенной своей логикой, а мне надо просто полностью скопировать объект, на первый взгляд вроде подходит `copy.deepcopy`

Comment: Да, Вы правы, 'copy.deepcopy` будет подходящим вариантом на случай, если в качестве параметра может быть список

Answer (score 0):

```
class data(list):
    def __init__(self,initial_list):
        self.list=initial_list

    def append(self,iterable):
        self.list.append(iterable)

    def extend(self,obj):
        self.list.extend(obj)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.list)

a=data([])
[]
a.append([1,2])
[[1, 2]]
a.extend([3,4])
[[1, 2], 3, 4]
```

Создаём унаследованный клас, от стандартного списка, далее изменяем стандартные методы. Я не спец, но скорее всего в стандартном классе списка имеется собственная переменная для хранения значений